# TortoiseGit Issue Tracker Integration for GitHub

Tags: git, version-control, github, tortoisegit, issue-tracking

TortoiseGit has a bunch of issue trackers integration plugins. One such useful plugin is [Gurtle](http://code.google.com/p/gurtle/) which shows the list of open issues during a commit operation so issues can be closed directly during commit.

Does such a plugin exist for GitHub issues integration? Are there any other similar tools for Github issues?

Screenshot of TortoiseGit + Google Code issue tracker integration:

[image: TortiseGit Issue Tracker Integration]

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [TurtleHub](https://github.com/dail8859/TurtleHub) works okay. You have to build it yourself and install following some [pretty arcane instructions](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/contrib/issue-tracker-plugins/issue-tracker-plugins.txt).  Since Google Code is going away soon, I'll quote those instructions here:

> Registering your new C# class can be done by using RegAsm from the command
>   line, as follows:
>
> ```
> RegAsm bin\Debug\MyCsPlugin.dll /codebase /regfile:MyCsPlugin.reg
> ```
>
> You'll need to edit the .REG file, by adding another "Implemented Categories"
>   entry that looks like this:
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{PUT-GUID-HERE}\Implemented Categories{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}]
>
> Replace "PUT-GUID-HERE" with the same value you used earlier.
>
> Then, merge that .REG file into the registry, and your plugin is ready to go!

The `RegAsm` command didn't work for me, so I had to provide its full path.  My command ended up looking like this:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe bin\Release\TurtleHub.dll /codebase /regfile:bin\Release\TurtleHub.reg
```

Next, I edited the resulting TurtleHub.reg file and added this line at the end:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{B2C6EC0F-8742-4792-9FDC-10635D2C118B}\Implemented Categories\{3494FA92-B139-4730-9591-01135D5E7831}]
```

After this, I double-clicked the .reg file to add it to the registry.

The parameters are fairly intuitive. There's only one: [username]/[reponame]